# Is mq_send atomic?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, real-time

can anybody tell me what happens if multithread program receives SIGSTOP signal during execution of mq_send?

Comment: so, I have done some test on my linux box (Linux home 2.6.31-11-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 11:06:40 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and it seems to be atomic, but I am not 100% sure. If anybody knows the exact answer or knows how mq_send works it would be nice to share info with us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for `mq_send` indicates it is implemented on top of `mq_timedsend`, which is a system call in Linux. System calls are generally atomic in that they either succeed or they don't. If a system call is interrupted by a signal, the usual behavior is to return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR`. It looks like `mq_send` has this behavior.

Basically, you should check for `EINTR`, and retry the call if it fails in this way. This is particularly important for system calls that may block like `recv` or `select`, since they have a higher chance of being interrupted.